# Dojo Dialog.show() not working

Tags: javascript, rest, dojo

I want to display JSON from a JsonRest within a Dojo Selectbox (dijit.form.select). Therefore, i have the following code:

```
    var processStore = new JsonRest({
                target: "http://cnwin.ebusiness.local/activiti-rest/service/repository/process-definitions?startableByUser=kermit", 
                headers: {"Authorization": "Basic a2VybWl0Omtlcm1pdA=="}, 
                allowNoTrailingSlash: false
                });

var myWidget = dijit.byId("processList");
myWidget.setStore(processStore);
this.show();
```

`This` is a dijit/Dialog. This code works fine and the Dialog is displayed. But the REST-Call is asynchronous. When I add the following method arround this code block, the line `this.show()` does not work anymore:

```
    var processStore = new JsonRest({
    target: "http://cnwin.ebusiness.local/activiti-rest/service/repository/process-definitions?startableByUser=kermit", 
    headers: {"Authorization": "Basic a2VybWl0Omtlcm1pdA=="}, 
    allowNoTrailingSlash: false
    });

processStore.query().then(function(response){
var myWidget = dijit.byId("processList");
    myWidget.setStore(processStore);
    this.show();
}
```

With printlns, I could see that all commands are executed except the last one (`this.show()`)
Has onyone an idea?

Thanks for your answers and best regards
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the this.show() is no longer within the scope of the dialog box.

You may want to try the following:

```
var processStore = new JsonRest({
    target: "http://cnwin.ebusiness.local/activiti-rest/service/repository/process-definitions?startableByUser=kermit", 
    headers: {"Authorization": "Basic a2VybWl0Omtlcm1pdA=="}, 
    allowNoTrailingSlash: false
});

var self = this;  // You can keep the scope of this saved
processStore.query().then(function(response){
    var myWidget = dijit.byId("processList");
    myWidget.setStore(processStore);
    self.show();  // Now self points to the dialog box
}
```

By adding the var self = this;  and then using self.show() in the function, the self should be the dialog box.